# Angular 2 Ionic - Create a new directive

Tags: angular, typescript, angularjs-directive, ionic2, angular2-directives

**I am trying to create a new directive in order to swipeUp objects, so like** `onSwipeUp="doThisFunction()"`

Here is a forum where other people want to do the same : 
https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/unable-to-catch-vertical-swipe-drag-events/46380/4

Here is my app.module.ts

```
import { SwipeVertical } from '../directives/swipe-vertical.directive';
@NgModule({
      declarations: [
        SwipeVertical
      ]
```

Here my home.ts

```
import { SwipeVertical } from "../../directives/swipe-vertical.directive.ts";

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html',
})
```

And in home.html I will use  :

```
<img class="imgUser" (onSwipeUp)="getLike(user, $event)" [src]="user.imgLink">
```

And my directive swipe-vertical.directive.ts

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, Output, OnInit, OnDestroy, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';
import {Gesture} from 'ionic-angular/gestures/gesture';
declare var Hammer: any;

@Directive({
    selector: '[swipe-vertical]'
})
export class SwipeVertical implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    @Output() onSwipeUp = new EventEmitter();
    @Output() onSwipeDown = new EventEmitter();

    private el: HTMLElement;
    private swipeGesture: Gesture;
    //private swipeDownGesture: Gesture;

    constructor(el: ElementRef) {
        this.el = el.nativeElement;
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.swipeGesture = new Gesture(this.el, {
            recognizers: [
                [Hammer.Swipe, {direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_VERTICAL}]
            ]
        });
        this.swipeGesture.listen();
        this.swipeGesture.on('swipeup', e => {
            this.onSwipeUp.emit({ el: this.el });
        });
        this.swipeGesture.on('swipedown', e => {
            this.onSwipeDown.emit({ el: this.el });
        });
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.swipeGesture.destroy();
    }
}
```

## Error

There are no errors, but the directive (onSwipeUp) is not working ..
Maybe add a section like this ? :

```
host: {
      "[onSwipeUp]": "SwipeUp" 
      }
```

Thank you very much for your help ! I appreciate it
Luis :)

Comment: are you sure the path is correct?

Comment: Yeah I solved this problem thank you ! Now there are no errors, but it's not working :/

Comment: well the plunkr seems to be working